# Laptop/Monitor KVM switch

Tags: macbook, external-display, kvm-switch

I have a Macbook Pro which I usually use via MiniDVI to VGA with an external monitor (plus thsi inbuilt LCD makes 2 displays). I've just bought a new Alienware which I'll be using with two monitors, one of which will be the existing monitor I have. Is there a good monitor switch which will let me keep one monitor connected to the desktop at all times, then switch the other one between laptop and desktop? It doesn't need to switch the mouse/keyboard as I tend to use the Macbook keyboard on the Macbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any KVM will do this provided it has a method of switching (such as a physical switch) that doesn't require a keyboard to be plugged in.

You would simply connect the two video inputs into the KVM and the video out to the screen, and ignore the keyboard and mouse ports.

Comment: I thought there may be one designed for this situation.